# Restrict Access to certain objects from Global Search

Tags: custom-object, search

I want to be able to restrict access to some of the objects from the global search.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you use a visual force page? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're trying to hide a specific record, or an entire object from the search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to completely block out an object, dont create a tab for it, and it doesn't show up in the search.

However, for all other cases, as long as the sharing settings permit the user to see the data, and if it matches the search expression, it will be returned in the results.

Comment: I want to hide the global search for chatter tab in communities (Manage Communities --> Edit --> Click on Tabs and Pages -->Select standard salesforce tabs --> select chatter tab..When i did this and when i change from Internal to Communities on the header I see the global search box)

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't provide many details of what's the exact scenario but in general you need to start by reviewing your organization sharing settings: Organization Wide defaults, sharing rules, role hierarchy.

By not creating a tab as suggested in another answer you prevent this object showing up in the global search but it doesn't prevent accessing to those records directly or reporting on those records.